# Incompatible VerifyCsrfToken issue

Tags: laravel, composer-php, token, vendor

After updating composer and changing few line of codes I got:

> ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 7: Declaration of
>   App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::handle($request,
>   App\Http\Middleware\Closure $next) should be compatible with
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::handle($request,
>   Closure $next)

What doest that mean and how to solve it?

[image]

I try to remove all from vendor folder and install whole libraries again with command composer update but won't work.

Comment: I also clear everything from cache folder and session folder and view folder ...

Comment: How to solve this please???

Comment: Do you have `{{ csrf_field() }}` or `{{ csrf_token() }}` inside your form/elements ?

Comment: yes, I have........

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the `$request` something like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
      //Your code goes here
      return $next($request);
}
```

Answer referrence [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/errorexception-in-verifycsrftoken?page=1)